# Не работает отправка валидных данных submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, которая валидирует введенные данные и отправляет их. 
Проверка работает корректно (если ошибка появляется сообщение об этом)

```
$('#validateForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        $inputs = $this.find('input[type!="submit"]'),
        is_valid = true;

    $inputs.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            rules = $this.data('validate').split(' ');

        for(var i = 0, ci = rules.length; i < ci; i++) {
            if(!validator[rules[i]]($this)) {
                validator.markAsError($this);

                $this.next().html(validator.messages(rules[i]));

                is_valid &= false;
                return;
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('error');
                $this.next().html('');
            }
        }
    });

    return is_valid;
});
```

В случае правильного заполнения полей, при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" - отправка не происходит. В консоли ошибок нет.
В чем может быть причина?

Полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/1v2hdkc0/)

Comment: Перенеси `event.preventDefault();` туда, где находишь ошибку - эта строчка как раз отключает отправку

Comment: метод как раз и находится там где проверка проводится. т.е. отменяет отправку если введены не корректные данные

Comment: Нет, твой метод сначала отменяет отправку (прям первой строчкой), а потом уже проверяет данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#validateForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    ....
    //Для каждого инпута
    $inputs.each(function() {
        ....
        //Для каждого правила
        for(var i = 0, ci = rules.length; i < ci; i++) {
            //Проверяем инпут правилом на валидность.
            if(!validator[rules[i]]($this)) {
                //Если инпут (хотя бы один) не валидный - отключаем отправку.
                event.preventDefault();
                ....
            } else {
                //А если валидный - то не отключаем. 
                ...
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде помогло! т.е. если данные из формы пропадают при нажатии на кнопку, значит они отправлены?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova не обязательно, но в вашем случае скорее всего да.  Если страница обновляется - то точно да.

Answer (score 3):

так отправки то нету - вот и не отправляет, а стандартное поведение ты отключаешь:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

**UPDATE** вот примерно как делать:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var name = $('#field').val();
    if (name  === '') { // не прошло проверку (пустое)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: отключаю, потому что перед отправкой д.б. валидация

Comment: @MarinaVoronova: То что К. написал Вам можно переформулировать так: `event.preventDefault();` следует выполнять не вначала, а только в том случае, когда вы нашли "инвалидов" в данных.

Comment: попробовала перенести этот метод после строки `$inputs.each(function() {...}` не помогло. для этого необходима дополнительная функция?